# sed append after match?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file like this: (is much longer though)

```
     1  5.60
     2  6.20
     3  6.58
     4  7.32
     5  8.10
     6  7.70
```

how can I use `sed` to make the list like this:

```
     1: 5.60
     2: 6.20
     3: 6.58
     4: 7.32
     5: 8.10
     6: 7.70
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when it hits `10`? `100`?

Comment: Oops. It basically goes with no trailing 0's: 1, 10, 99, 100, up to 127.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(\S\)\s/\1:/' your_file
```

This should work with multiple digit numbers as well, as long as there is always at least one space between the two numbers on each line.

Comment: This does not seem to work, it just has the same output as cat'ing the file. EDIT: I found the problem, the file is using TAB characters ("\t").  Thanks. but can you explain the '\S' ? and the "\\(\\)"

Comment: I edited my answer so that it should work regardless of whether tabs or spaces are used.  The `\S` means any character that is not whitespace, and the `\s` that I added to the regex matches any whitespace character.  The `\(\)` puts whatever is between the parentheses into a group, which can be referenced in the replacement with `\1` (since it is the first and only group).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use awk for this like this:

```
awk 'NF==2{printf("%s: %s\n", $1, $2);}' file.txt
```

#### OUTPUT

```
1: 5.60
2: 6.20
3: 6.58
4: 7.32
5: 8.10
6: 7.70
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate sed solution is:

> sed -E 's/^([[0-9]+)/\1:/' your_file

This just replaces any string of digits at the beginning of a line with those digits followed by a colon.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me -- essentially \1 matches the first number and \2 matches the rest.

```
sed 's/\( *[0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1:\2/' file.txt
```